# How to customize "Notification Web API" in the QT

Tags: c++, qt, qtwebkit, qwebpage

I'm creating a simple browser using [**QtWebkit**](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebkit-index.html), I managed to add support for [**Notification Web API**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification) it, using `QWebPage::setFeaturePermission`.

Example:

```
function notifyMe() {
    if (Notification.permission === "granted") {
        var notification = new Notification("Hi there!");
    } else if (Notification.permission !== "denied") {
        Notification.requestPermission(function(permission) {
            if (permission === "granted") {
                var notification = new Notification("Hi there!");
            }
        });
    }
}

<button onclick="notifyMe();">Notify me</button>
```

My code:

```
QObject::connect(page,
    SIGNAL(featurePermissionRequested(QWebFrame*, QWebPage::Feature)), this,
    SLOT(featurePermissionRequested(QWebFrame*,QWebPage::Feature))
);

...

void Form::featurePermissionRequested(QWebFrame* frame, QWebPage::Feature feature) {
    switch (feature) {
        case QWebPage::Notifications:
            qDebug() << "Notification";
            page->setFeaturePermission(frame, feature, QWebPage::PermissionGrantedByUser);
        break;
        case QWebPage::Geolocation:
            qDebug() << "GEO";
        break;
        default:
            qDebug() << "Unknown feature";
    }
}
```

Every time I click on the *"Notify me"* button the following message appears on the desktop:

[image: Desktop Notification]

It is possible to customize the notifications in QT? In other words, leave similar to the GoogleChrome or Firefox, like this:

[image: Web Notification]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To customize `Notifications Web API` in `QtWebkit` you must use the "Webkit plugins", in other words create a plugin and put in the `qtdir/plugins/webkit`.

> **Note:** For create plugin is needed `<QtWebKit/QWebKitPlatformPlugin>` class

### Create the plugin:

- Create a project in QtCreator
- In `.pro` file use (example `src.pro`):

  ```
  TARGET = $$qtLibraryTarget(mywebkitplugin)
  TEMPLATE = lib
  CONFIG += plugin

  HEADERS += $$[QT_INSTALL_HEADERS]/QtWebKit/qwebkitplatformplugin.h \
      mywebkitplugin.h

  SOURCES += \
      mywebkitplugin.cpp

  Release:DESTDIR     = $$PWD/bin/release
  Release:UI_DIR      = $${DESTDIR}/.ui
  Release:MOC_DIR     = $${DESTDIR}/.moc
  Release:RCC_DIR     = $${DESTDIR}/.rcc
  Release:OBJECTS_DIR = $${DESTDIR}/.obj

  Debug:DESTDIR       = $$PWD/bin/debug
  Debug:UI_DIR        = $${DESTDIR}/.ui
  Debug:MOC_DIR       = $${DESTDIR}/.moc
  Debug:RCC_DIR       = $${DESTDIR}/.rcc
  Debug:OBJECTS_DIR   = $${DESTDIR}/.obj
  ```
- Create mywebkitplugin.h

  ```
  #ifndef MYWEBKITPLUGIN_H
  #define MYWEBKITPLUGIN_H

  #include <QtWebKit/QWebKitPlatformPlugin>

  class MyWebKitPlugin : public QObject, public QWebKitPlatformPlugin
  {
      Q_OBJECT
      Q_INTERFACES(QWebKitPlatformPlugin)

  #if QT_VERSION >= 0x050000
      Q_PLUGIN_METADATA(IID "org.qtwebkit.QtWebKit.QtWebPlugin")
  #endif

  public:
      explicit MyWebKitPlugin();
      ~MyWebKitPlugin();

      bool supportsExtension(Extension ext) const;
      QObject* createExtension(Extension ext) const;
  };

  #endif // MYWEBKITPLUGIN_H
  ```
- Create mywebkitplugin.cpp

  ```
  #include "mywebkitplugin.h"
  #include "notification/notification.h"

  MyWebKitPlugin::MyWebKitPlugin()
  {
  }

  MyWebKitPlugin::~MyWebKitPlugin()
  {
  }

  bool MyWebKitPlugin::supportsExtension(Extension ext) const
  {
      return ext == Notifications;
  }

  QObject* MyWebKitPlugin::createExtension(Extension ext) const
  {
      switch (ext) {
          case Notifications:
              return new Notification();

          default:
              return 0;
      }
  }

  //for QT-4.8
  #if QT_VERSION < 0x050000
  Q_EXPORT_PLUGIN2(webkitplugin, MyWebKitPlugin);
  #endif
  ```
- Create `notification` folder
- In notification folder put notification class:

  notification.h

  ```
  #ifndef NOTIFICATION_H
  #define NOTIFICATION_H

  #include <QtWebKit/QWebKitPlatformPlugin>

  class Notification : public QWebNotificationPresenter
  {
      Q_OBJECT

  public:
      explicit Notification();
      ~Notification();

      void showNotification(const QWebNotificationData* data);

  signals:
      void notificationClosed();
      void notificationClicked();
  };

  #endif // NOTIFICATION_H
  ```

  notification.cpp

  ```
  #include "notification.h"
  #include <QDebug>

  Notification::Notification() : QWebNotificationPresenter()
  {
      qDebug() << "Create: Notification";
  }

  Notification::~Notification()
  {
      qDebug() << "Delete: this (Notification)";
  }

  void Notification::showNotification(const QWebNotificationData* data)
  {
      qDebug() << "title:" << data->title();
      qDebug() << "icon:" << data->iconUrl();
      qDebug() << "message:" << data->message();
      qDebug() << "opener page:" << data->openerPageUrl();
  }
  ```

For create your notification customized change `Notification::showNotification(const QWebNotificationData* data)` content and use `QWebNotificationData* data` for get data from `JavaScript API`.

- Create `notification.pri` (included in `src.pro`):

  ```
  QT += network

  HEADERS += \
      $$PWD/notification.h

  SOURCES += \
      $$PWD/notification.cpp
  ```
- Add `notification.pri` in `src.pro`:

  ```
  include($$PWD/notification/notification.pri)
  ```

### Compiling/build:

- Open `src.pro` in QtCreator
- Click in `Build` (in Release Mode) (or use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>) button (**don't click** in `Run` button, **don't use** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>)
- Close `src.pro`
- Go to the folder that is located the `src.pro`
- (If release mode) Open `bin/release` folder
- (If debug mode) Open `bin/debug` folder
- (If release mode) Copy `mywebkitplugin.dll` to `QtDir/plugins/webkit/mywebkitplugin.dll` (eg with mingw: `C:/qt/qt5.4/mingw/plugin/webkit/mywebkitplugin.dll`)
- (If debug mode) Copy `mywebkitplugind.dll` to `QtDir/plugins/webkit/mywebkitplugind.dll` (eg with mingw: `C:/qt/qt5.4/mingw/plugin/webkit/mywebkitplugind.dll`)
- If `webkit` folder does not exist, create it.
- Open your project with `QWebView` and test `Notification Web API`.

When running a project that uses `QWebView`, it will automatically load the `dll` (no needs extras configurations in your project) and will "replace" the default `Notifications` (`QtWebkit` in Windows uses `SystemTrayIcon` for show `Notification Web API`) for your "custom widget".

### Folder structure for plugin projetct:

```
mywebkitplugin
├── `src.pro`
├── mywebkitplugin.h
├── mywebkitplugin.cpp
└── notification
    ├── notification.h
    ├── notification.cpp
    └── `notification.pri`
```

Answer (score 0):

The new notification can take 2 parameters as below :

```
var notification = new Notification(title, options);
```

As part of options object, you can pass the 'body'  and the 'icon' to be displayed in the notification.

Comment: Where do YOU READ that my problem is with JavaScript? I recommend that before answering anything read whole question. The notification works perfectly, what I asked is how to customize the `widget` generated by notification, in other words, I want to change `systemtray widget` for `custom widget`. Sorry sincerity (I hope not take offense), but their response attempt seems *"hunter points"* and not an attempt to help. Sorry again sincerity, have a nice day.

Comment: Im sorry my answer is incomplete as it doesn't address the complete problem, only points out the possibility , should have put it as a comment.

Comment: Sorry again, but your answer does not address anything that was asked (even if it was a comment). In the title I have made clear that the issue is about "QT" and in question also. I hope it was clear that the `qtwebkit` works perfectly with `Notification Web API` and the issue is about to replace the `default notification` (default in QT uses the *SystemTray*) by **"custom widget"**. Thanks for read my comment :)